# Combolist box to listbox counter can't reset to zero

Tags: visual-studio, listbox

So I'm loading data into from an array to the combolist box and then if its selected its load into my listbox. I'm also incrementing & decrementing values as they are being uncheck and checked but I can't seem to hit 0 it seems like 1 is the minimum. I tried adding checkstate.unchecked and removing my for loops but it became a mess.

```
 Private Sub combolistbox_ItemCheck(sender As Object, _e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles cblCourses.ItemCheck
    Dim item As String
    Dim price As Integer = 0
    Dim Amount1 As Integer = 0
    Dim Amount2 As Integer = 0


    item = combolistbox.SelectedItem.ToString()


    If (_e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked) Then
        If Not listbox.Items.Contains(item) Then

            listbox.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Else
        listbox.Items.Remove(item)
    End If


    For i = 0 To job_1.Length - 1

        If listbox.Items.Contains(job_1(i)) Then
            price += dayCourse
            label_bulk.Text = FormatCurrency(price)
            Amount1 += 1
            label_Day.Text = (AmountDay1)
        End If
    Next


    For i = 0 To job_2.Length - 1

        If listbox.Items.Contains(job_2(i)) Then
            price += eveningCourse
            label_bulk.Text = FormatCurrency(price)
            Amount2 += 1
            label_Evening.Text = (Amount2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but you have `label_Day.Text = (AmountDay)` and `label_Evening.Text = (Amount2)`.  Should the first one be `Amount1` instead of `AmountDay`?  If you have `Option Strict Off` then it wouldn't flag as an error.

Comment: The add/remove part seems to work fine for me.  Not sure exactly how the  two loops down below are supposed to work, however; if that is where your problem lies?...

Comment: label_Day.Text = (AmountDay) was my fault and I've already corrected before I posted.  And for my for loops they loop through an array of strings that populate my combolist box. if I find one of my elements in the array i start to increment some values.